# Is u • v equal to |u • v|?

Tags: vectors

The following is a homework problem from an introductory course in linear algebra with the instructor's answer:

> **Question:** Use the geometric description of the dot product to verify the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and to show that equality occurs
>   if and only if one of the vectors is a scalar multiple of the other.
>
> **Answer:** This formula says that
>    $$u · v = |u| |v| \cos θ$$
>   where θ is the included angle between the two vectors. Thus 
>   $$|u · v| = |u||v| |\cos θ| ≤ |u| |v|$$ 
>   and equality holds if and only if θ = 0 or π.
>   This means that the two vectors either point in the same direction or
>   opposite directions. Hence one is a multiple of the other.

My question is this: it appears that the $$u·v$$ used in his proof is suddenly equal to $$|u·v|$$  Is this true?  Why?

Comment: It might help to use $\|u\|$ rather than $|u|$ for norms, and save $|\cdot|$ for absolute values...

Comment: No, it is not said that $|u\cdot v|=u\cdot v$. It is said that an equality with $u\cdot v$ induces another equality with $|u\cdot v|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$u\cdot v$ is not the same as $|u\cdot v|$, as the former can be negative. The author is simply starting with the equation 
$$u\cdot v=|u||v|\cos(\theta)$$
and then taking the absolute value of each side.

Comment: So somehow I need to differentiate between $|u|$ meaning magnitude of $u$ and $|u|$ meaning absolute value of $u$?

Comment: Well, yes, context. $u \cdot v$ is a scalar.

Comment: There isn't really anything to differentiate, absolute value and magnitude are kind of the same thing. What we call 'absolute value' is just a 1-dimensional version of magnitude, both tell you 'how big' something is, without caring about direction.

Answer (score 0):

If your $u,v\in\mathbb{R^n}$(say $u=(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ and $v=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$) then you should be considering the function$$\cdot:\mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$$ defined by$$\cdot(u,v)=u\cdot v=u_1v_1+\cdots+u_nv_n$$ as the dot product.

So $u\cdot v\in\mathbb{R} $ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$ $x\le|x|$.

**Note:** Here you are not differentiating between a vector and its magnitude, but you are comparing two real numbers using the definition of absolute value of a real number.